# Using variables in modules of Node Express application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

The express generator creates an app like this:
in the main app.js:

```
var app = express();
//...
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
//...
```

in routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

What is the best way to use variables that I define in app.js in the index.js?
For example, before defining the routes, I set up the mongoose model:

```
var myModel;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;

db.once('open', function (callback) {
    //load schemas
    var dbSchema = require('./schema');
    myModel = mongoose.model('mymodel', dbSchema.myModel);
});
```

How can I use 'myModel' in the routes module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define your models outside **app.js**, in their own separate files for each separate model, and export that model which you can then `require` in various places you need it. Your model definition doesn't actually need to be inside `db.once('open'`

For example: if you have a model **User** you should define it in its own file like this:

**db/user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
    …
});
var model = mongoose.model('user', schema);
module.exports = model;
```

This way if you want to use the User model inside your **routes/index.js**:

```
…
var User = require('../db/user');
router.get('/user/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user){
        res.render('user', { title: 'Express', user: user});    
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as a parameter when you require your router in your app.js file. You're going to have to slightly modify your index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var myRouter = function(myModel) {
    var router = express.Router();

    /* GET home page. */
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
    });

    // You can use your myModel model here

    return router;
}

module.exports = myRouter
```

Now inside your app.js

```
var app = express();
//...
// Pass myModel as a parameter
var routes = require('./routes/index')(myModel);
app.use('/', routes);
//...
```